# ETL flow for taking data from a remote service, transforming it to a local ORM Model, then setting up relationships?

Tags: kiba-etl

I recently set up my first "etl" flow to take data from a remote service, modify it to fit my local models, then save it.  Now that I've finished, it feels rather grotesque for a few reasons

my `source` is the JSON from the remote service

my `transform` replaces each `row` with a newly defined local `model`, based on the original `source` `row`

`transform` also looks at various values and defines additional local relationships

`destination` then calls `.save` on my newly replaced `rows` which are now models in the ORM.

1. How am I supposed to create local records based on an external datasource? My models don't look like the remote sources.  Is it right to supplant a `row` entry with my new Model object?
2. If I am supposed to replace the value of `row` with my local model, then I presume I should split each subsequent action into a `transform` on that new row (now a model)?

In all, my .etl looks like

```
pre_process do
  @some = <Go To DB and fetch data>
  @variables = <Setup More Information>
end

source MyRemoteSource

transform DoABunchOfWork,@some,@variables

destination CallSaveOnModels
```

DoABunchOfWork class has about 6 methods that `process` will call to manipulate or setup relationships in various ways

Comment: Hi! Author of Kiba here. Your question is probably not very complicated to answer, yet I'm missing a few details. Can you email me (thibaut.barrere at gmail.com) so that we discuss this privately, and I will make a detailed public answer afterwards? Thanks!

Comment: I emailed you further details, thank you!